# Get rid of special caret mode in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, caret

I use Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 18.04 to write Markdown documents. Sometimes, when I'm writing a list with bullet points, the caret seems to enter a special mode. In that mode, anytime I type a space, the caret background is grayed out like in the picture below (taking a screenshot made the caret disappear, but it's supposed to show in the middle of the small gray block).

[image: ST caret issue]

Some keys' behavior also change. For instance, typing `shift + TAB` folds the current section of the document, while it normally decreases the list indent. I haven't been able to figure out exactly what combination of keys (something with TAB?) and circumstances leads to that situation. To get rid of it, I need to press `Enter` enough times to exit the bulleted list mode.

Any idea what that is and how I can prevent it from happening?

Comment: Do you have some package like MarkdownEditing or similar installed?

Comment: I do have MarkdownEditing installed.

Comment: I would try disabling that package and seeing if the problem keeps happening, to narrow it down.